# If statement not working when using raw_input

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

The code works when I don't use raw_input. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using python 2.7.5 Here is my code:

```
mark = raw_input('Enter Your Marks: ')

x = mark

if x > 80:
    grade = 'HD'
elif x > 70:
    grade = 'D'
elif x > 60:
    grade = 'CR'
elif x > 50:
    grade = 'P'
else:
    grade = 'F'

print(grade)
```

Comment: You need to convert the value from a string to an integer before you can compare it with other integers meaningfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input()` returns a string, but you are comparing against integers.

Convert your input:

```
x = int(mark)
```